# How to know the credentials for Magento Connect?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect

I'm now responsable of manager a Magento store 1.9.3 located in Google cloud Server. I need to update one of our extension via Magento connect. 
The problem is that I don't know the credentials to login to Magento Connect.

[image]

There is a way to get the credentials? I have access to the server via FTP and SSH.

Comment: check answer from @Mohit Kumar Arora. This is you solution of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot posted in the question, it seems that Magento connect credentials are not required here.

This pop-up seems to be applied by .htpasswd file.

You need to check .htaccess file in the document root and try to find the location of .htpasswd.

Now, you either need to remove below code to remove this authentication:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /[location of .htpasswd file]/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

or, you need to navigate to [location of .htpasswd file] and change the password in following format:

```
user:encrypted-password
```

Below is an example:

```
mohit:$apr1$3w5jkhya$8vTWZpaItX5KY/fBGtRen0
```

You can generate the encrypted password from [here](https://www.web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator).

**Update:** After either removing the pop-up or logging in from the pop-up, you need to login to Magento Connect using your own administrator account credentials.

Please let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: Mohit, thanks for your reply. The problem was solved! thanks again for your help. Regards!

Comment: Glad to know that your problem has been resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Use same username and password which use for admin login